# Pass 2D array of bytes to C in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi, rust-bindgen

I've written a function in C with this signature:

```
write_stuff(char **pages, uint32 page_count);
```

`pages` will be an array of 128 elements, with each element either NULL or pointing to a char array of 8192 bytes. So, an array of arrays with fixed, known sizes.

I need to populate the arrays in Rust and pass them to the C function. When I generate a Rust signature using bindgen, it produces this:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn write_stuff(pages: *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char, page_count: u32,);
}
```

Now, how do I declare a variable in Rust that I can populate and pass to this function?

I tried this:

```
let mut pages = [Option <[u8; 8192]>; 128];
```

but it doesn't compile.

This does compile:

```
type MyPage = Option<[u8; 8192]>;
let myarray: [MyPage; 128] = [None; 128];
```

but I'm not clear on whether it would store the data in the right format, or how to cast it appropriately:

```
let pages: *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char = myarray.as_mut_ptr() as // what goes here?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Rust type you're looking for is `&[Option<&[u8; 8192]>]`.
The C version uses a double pointer, so you need to make sure the inner type is a reference . `Option<&T>` shows that the reference is nullable and the [null pointer optimization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html#representation) guarantees that it has the same size as `T`.

I've tested that the code below works as expected,
but I'm not 100% sure this type conversion is sound
so I'd be careful using this in production code.

**Rust main.rs**

```
#[link(name = "mylib")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn write_stuff(pages: *mut *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char, page_count: u32);
}

pub fn write_stuff_rust(pages: &[Option<&[u8; 8192]>]) {
    unsafe { write_stuff(pages.as_ptr() as *mut _, pages.len() as u32) }
}

fn main() {
    let page1: [u8; 8192] = [b'a'; 8192];
    let page3: [u8; 8192] = [b'b'; 8192];
    let page4: [u8; 8192] = [b'c'; 8192];
    let page7: [u8; 8192] = [b'd'; 8192];

    let pages: Vec<Option<&[u8; 8192]>> = vec![
        Some(&page1),
        None,
        Some(&page3),
        Some(&page4),
        None,
        None,
        Some(&page7),
    ];

    write_stuff_rust(&pages);
}
```

**C mylib.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void write_stuff(char **pages, uint32_t page_count) {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < page_count; i++) {
        printf("%d=%p\n", i, pages[i]);
        if (pages[i]) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < 8192; j++) {
                putchar(pages[i][j]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
        } else {
            puts("<empty>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is outstanding. You've gone above and beyond.

Comment: This is sound, however: a) better to use `&[Option<&[u8; 8192]>; 128]` (gives the compiler more knowledge, thus better optimizations). b) If the C code changes the references it's UB (since they're created from shared references), and if it's not it's better to change them to `*const` (or `const *` in C).

Comment: Caution. The code above works, but similar code I wrote did not because I created the pages vec in a function and returned a raw pointer to it. The vec went out of scope and its memory was freed. Rust does not track the lifetime of raw pointers.